# ¿Cómo puedo leer un dato especifico dentro de un campo en un tabla mysql json anidada usando php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Mi base de datos en mysql está compuesta de la siguiente manera: tiene una tabla llamada "ventas" donde hay un campo "productos" donde esta grabado unos datos en json array nested y dentro de este json solo necesito sacar la información "marca" "modelo" para poder mostrarlo en un datatable(tener en cuenta dentro del campos "productos" puede tener hasta 10 productos grabados *********** se necesita imprimir todos los productos*********** ), Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image]

```
<div class="content-wrapper">

  <section class="content-header">

    <h1>

      Administrar ventas

    </h1>

    <ol class="breadcrumb">

      <li><a href="inicio"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Inicio</a></li>

      <li class="active">Administrar ventas</li>

    </ol>

  </section>

  <section class="content">

    <div class="box">

      <div class="box-header with-border">

        <a href="crear-venta">

          <button class="btn btn-primary">

            Agregar venta

          </button>

        </a>

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="daterange-btn">

            <span>
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Rango de fecha
            </span>

            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>

         </button>

      </div>

      <div class="box-body">

       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive tablas" width="100%">

        <thead>

         <tr>

           <th style="width:10px">#</th>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>Vendedor</th>
           <th>Cliente</th>
           <th>Proviene</th>
           <th>Producto</th>
           <th>Despacho</th>
           <th>Adelanto</th>
           <th>Total</th>            
           <th>Estado</th>
           <th>Obs.</th>
           <th>Fecha Compra</th>
           <th>Acciones</th>

         </tr> 

        </thead>

        <tbody>

        <?php

          if(isset($_GET["fechaInicial"])){

            $fechaInicial = $_GET["fechaInicial"];
            $fechaFinal = $_GET["fechaFinal"];

          }else{

            $fechaInicial = null;
            $fechaFinal = null;

          }

          $respuesta = ControladorVentas::ctrRangoFechasVentas($fechaInicial, $fechaFinal);

          foreach ($respuesta as $key => $value) {

           echo '<tr>

                  <td>'.($key+1).'</td>

                  <td>'.$value["codigo"].'</td>';

                    $itemUsuario = "id";
                  $valorUsuario = $value["id_vendedor"];

                  $respuestaUsuario = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($itemUsuario, $valorUsuario);

                  echo '<td>'.$respuestaUsuario["nombre"].'</td>';

                  $itemCliente = "id";
                  $valorCliente = $value["id_cliente"];

                  $respuestaCliente = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($itemCliente, $valorCliente);

                  echo '<td>'.$respuestaCliente["nombre"].'</td>

                  <td>'.$value["proviene"].'</td>

                  <td>'.$value["productos"].'</td>

                  <td>S/.'.number_format($value["desp"],2).'</td>
                  <td>S/.'.number_format($value["adelanto"],2).'</td>
                  <td bgcolor="#DCDCDC">S/. '.number_format($value["total"] + $value["desp"] - $value["descuento"]  ,2).'</td>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">'.$value["estado"].'</td>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFE4C4">'.$value["obs"].'</td>
                  <td>'.$value["fecha"].'</td>

                  <td>

                    <div class="btn-group">

                      <button class="btn btn-info btnImprimirFactura" codigoVenta="'.$value["codigo"].'">

                        <i class="fa fa-print"></i>

                      </button>';

                      if($_SESSION["perfil"] == "Administrador"){

                      echo '<button class="btn btn-warning btnEditarVenta" idVenta="'.$value["id"].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>

                      <button class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarVenta" idVenta="'.$value["id"].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>';

                    }


                    if($_SESSION["perfil"] == "Administrador2"){

                      echo '<button class="btn btn-warning btnEditarVenta" idVenta="'.$value["id"].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>';

                    }

                    if($_SESSION["perfil"] == "Especial"){

                      echo '<button class="btn btn-warning btnEditarVenta" idVenta="'.$value["id"].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>';

                    }


                    echo '</div>  

                  </td>

                </tr>';
            }

        ?>

        </tbody>

       </table>

       <?php

      $eliminarVenta = new ControladorVentas();
      $eliminarVenta -> ctrEliminarVenta();

      ?>


      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

***Tener en cuenta que este json esta dentro del campo "productos" de la Tabla Ventas***

```
    [{
"id":"312",
"marca":"NIKON",
"modelo":"D3400",
"serie":"8857882",
"cantidad":"1",
"stock":"0",
"precio":"1669",
"total":"1669"
},
{"id":"161",
"marca":"NIKON",
"modelo":"AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G",
"serie":"21963658",
"cantidad":"1",
"stock":"0",
"precio":"0",
"total":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Si dentro de `productos` hay algo como esto:

```
[{
    "id": "312",
    "marca": "NIKON",
    "modelo": "D3400",
    "serie": "8857882",
    "cantidad": "1",
    "stock": "0",
    "precio": "1669",
    "total": "1669"
}, {
    "id": "161",
    "marca": "NIKON",
    "modelo": "AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G",
    "serie": "21963658",
    "cantidad": "1",
    "stock": "0",
    "precio": "0",
    "total": "0"
}]
```

Lo podrás leer haciendo lo siguiente:

1. Conviertes el string tipo JSON a una variable PHP mediante [**`json_decode`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php). Le pasas `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` para que no agregue caracteres de escape  `\` al resultado.
2. Lees los datos dentro de dos  `foreach` anidados, puesto que hay varios objetos JSON dentro

Por ejemplo:

```
$productos=
'
[{
    "id": "312",
    "marca": "NIKON",
    "modelo": "D3400",
    "serie": "8857882",
    "cantidad": "1",
    "stock": "0",
    "precio": "1669",
    "total": "1669"
}, {
    "id": "161",
    "marca": "NIKON",
    "modelo": "AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G",
    "serie": "21963658",
    "cantidad": "1",
    "stock": "0",
    "precio": "0",
    "total": "0"
}]
';
$json=json_decode($productos,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

foreach ($json as $item){
    foreach($item as $k=>$v){
        echo "$k: $v".PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL."--------------------------".PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

**Salida:**

```
id: 312
marca: NIKON
modelo: D3400
serie: 8857882
cantidad: 1
stock: 0
precio: 1669
total: 1669

--------------------------
id: 161
marca: NIKON
modelo: AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G
serie: 21963658
cantidad: 1
stock: 0
precio: 0
total: 0

--------------------------
```